# window.scrollTo on iPad/iPhone orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Upon load, I am positioning the users scroll to the top of the '#gallery-view' element.

This is working correctly on iPad and iPhone. However, if I change the orientation of the device, its not positioning.

I have run tests to check the code is run on orientation change. The 'resize' option is triggering correctly and the 'test' console.log is output.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function winResize() {

    if ( jQuery('#gallery-view').length ) {

        console.log('test');

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, jQuery('#gallery-view').offset().top);
        }, 0);

    }

}

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {

    jQuery(window).resize(winResize); 
    winResize();

});
```

Does anyone know of any reason why this wouldn't trigger on orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching your `winResize` handler function to the `orientationchange` event as well. [See the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange).

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't make any difference.